# AVC profiles supported in MOV or MP4 container

Tags: mp4, h.264, profile, mov, bit-depth

I am looking for a list of AVC profiles supported in MOV and MP4 containers. In particular, I am interested in knowing if AVC High 10, AVC High 4:2:2, and AVC High 10 4:2:2 profiles are supported in MOV and MP4 containers. Is this information listed in some standard reference ?

Answer (score 1):

Mov and mp4 have no concept of profile. The profile is all encoded in the video sequence header and bitstream. Therefor mov and mp4 support all profiles and chroma sub sampling methods.

Players on the other hand, may not support all the profiles.